# Azure B2C/B2B direct connect

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

In my scenario I have Tenant A with B2C and Tenant B with normal AAD. I need enable to all users from Tenant B sign in to my application in Tenant A B2C. For now I do it with IDP and it works fine, but not so clear. When I tried to B2B direct connect I can connect, but user not create in Tenant A B2C tenant but maybe I set something bad. Is there any way or IDP is the best way?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow) is the best way.

This allows an Azure AD user to sign into a B2C application.

Comment: Yea but this is add AD as identity provider. I know its is way and i have it for now. My question was if is there another better way. Thank you

Comment: No - this is the way to do it.